# Pytorch - Getting gradient for intermediate variables / tensors

Tags: artificial-intelligence, pytorch, gradient-descent

As an exercice in pytorch framework (0.4.1) , I am trying to display the gradient of X (gX or dSdX) in a simple Linear layer (Z = X.W + B). To simplify my toy example, I backward() from a sum of Z (not a loss).

To sum up, I want gX(dSdX) of S=sum(XW+B).

**The problem is that the gradient of Z (dSdZ) is None**. As a result, gX is wrong too of course.

```
import torch
X = torch.tensor([[0.5, 0.3, 2.1], [0.2, 0.1, 1.1]], requires_grad=True)
W = torch.tensor([[2.1, 1.5], [-1.4, 0.5], [0.2, 1.1]])
B = torch.tensor([1.1, -0.3])
Z = torch.nn.functional.linear(X, weight=W.t(), bias=B)
S = torch.sum(Z)
S.backward()
print("Z:\n", Z)
print("gZ:\n", Z.grad)
print("gX:\n", X.grad)
```

Result:

```
Z:
 tensor([[2.1500, 2.9100],
        [1.6000, 1.2600]], grad_fn=<ThAddmmBackward>)
gZ:
 None
gX:
 tensor([[ 3.6000, -0.9000,  1.3000],
        [ 3.6000, -0.9000,  1.3000]])
```

I have exactly the same result if I use nn.Module as below:

```
class Net1Linear(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, wi, wo,W,B):
        super(Net1Linear, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = torch.nn.Linear(wi, wo)
        self.linear1.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(W.t())
        self.linear1.bias = torch.nn.Parameter(B)
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.linear1(x)
net = Net1Linear(3,2,W,B)
Z = net(X)
S = torch.sum(Z)
S.backward()
print("Z:\n", Z)
print("gZ:\n", Z.grad)
print("gX:\n", X.grad)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you only calculate gradients for tensors where you enable the gradient by setting the `requires_grad` to `True`.

So your output is just as one would expect. You get the gradient for `X`.

PyTorch does not save gradients of intermediate results for performance reasons. So you will just get the gradient for those tensors you set `requires_grad` to `True`.

However you can use `register_hook` to extract the intermediate grad during calculation or to save it manually. Here I just save it to the `grad` variable of tensor `Z`:

```py
import torch

# function to extract grad
def set_grad(var):
    def hook(grad):
        var.grad = grad
    return hook

X = torch.tensor([[0.5, 0.3, 2.1], [0.2, 0.1, 1.1]], requires_grad=True)
W = torch.tensor([[2.1, 1.5], [-1.4, 0.5], [0.2, 1.1]])
B = torch.tensor([1.1, -0.3])
Z = torch.nn.functional.linear(X, weight=W.t(), bias=B)

# register_hook for Z
Z.register_hook(set_grad(Z))

S = torch.sum(Z)
S.backward()
print("Z:\n", Z)
print("gZ:\n", Z.grad)
print("gX:\n", X.grad)
```

This will output:

```py
Z:
 tensor([[2.1500, 2.9100],
        [1.6000, 1.2600]], grad_fn=<ThAddmmBackward>)
gZ:
 tensor([[1., 1.],
        [1., 1.]])
gX:
 tensor([[ 3.6000, -0.9000,  1.3000],
        [ 3.6000, -0.9000,  1.3000]])
```

Hope this helps!

*Btw.: Normally you would want the gradient to be activated for your parameters - so your weights and biases. Because what you would do right now when using the optimizer, is altering your inputs `X` and not your weights `W` and bias `B`. So usually gradient is activated for `W` and `B` in such a case.*

Comment: NOTE: in production code, ensure the hooks are removed to avoid memory leaks. E.g follow `hook = Z.register_hook(...)` with `hook.remove()`

Answer (score 5):

There's a much simpler way. Simply use `retain_grad()`:

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.Tensor.retain_grad

```
Z.retain_grad()
```

before calling `backward()`

Answer (score 0):

blue-phoenox, thanks for your answer. I am pretty happy to have heard about register_hook().

What led me to think that I had a wrong gX is that it was independant of the values of X. I will have to do the math to understand it. But using CCE Loss instead of SUM makes things much more clean. So I updated the example for those who might be interested. Using SUM was a bad idea in this case.

```
T_dec = torch.tensor([0, 1])
X = torch.tensor([[0.5, 0.8, 2.1], [0.7, 0.1, 1.1]], requires_grad=True)
W = torch.tensor([[2.7, 0.5], [-1.4, 0.5], [0.2, 1.1]])
B = torch.tensor([1.1, -0.3])
Z = torch.nn.functional.linear(X, weight=W.t(), bias=B)
print("Z:\n", Z)
L = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(Z,T_dec)
Z.register_hook(lambda gZ: print("gZ:\n",gZ))
L.backward()
print("gX:\n", X.grad)
```

Result:

```
Z:
 tensor([[1.7500, 2.6600],
        [3.0700, 1.3100]], grad_fn=<ThAddmmBackward>)
gZ:
 tensor([[-0.3565,  0.3565],
        [ 0.4266, -0.4266]])
gX:
 tensor([[-0.7843,  0.6774,  0.3209],
        [ 0.9385, -0.8105, -0.3839]])
```