# How to do backprop in Pytorch (autograd.backward(loss) vs loss.backward()) and where to set requires_grad=True?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch, backpropagation

I have been using Pytorch for a while now. One question I had regarding backprop is as follows:

let's say we have a loss function for a neural network. For doing backprop, I have seen two different versions. One like:

```
optimizer.zero_grad()
autograd.backward(loss)
optimizer.step()
```

and the other one like:

```
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

Which one should I use? Is there any difference between these two versions?

As a last question, do we need to specify the `requires_grad=True` for the parameters of every layer of our network to make sure their gradients is being computed in the backprop?

For example do I need to specify it for the layer `nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)` inside my network or it is automatically being set to True by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so just a quick answer: both `autograd.backward(loss)` and `loss.backward()` are actually the same. Just look at [the implementation](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/_modules/torch/tensor.html#Tensor.backward) of `tensor.backward()` (as your loss is just a tensor), where `tensor.loss` just calls `autograd.backward(loss)`.

As to your second question: whenever you use a prefabricated layer such as `nn.Linear`, or convolutions, or RNNs, etc., all of them rely on `nn.Parameter` attributes to store the parameters values. And, [as the docs say](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=nn%20parameter#torch.nn.Parameter), these default with `requires_grad=True`.

Update to a follow-up in the comments: To answer what happens to tensors when they are in a backward pass depends on whether a variable is on the computation path between the "output" and a leaf variable, or not. If not, it is not entirely clear what backprop should compute - after all, the entire purpose is to compute gradients for parameters, i.e., leaf-variables. If the tensor is on that path, all gradients will generally be automatically computed. For a more thorough discussion, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53219600/pytorch-getting-gradient-for-intermediate-variables-tensors) and [this tutorial from the docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html).

Comment: Thanks! very well explained. One more question, when you define your own Tensor variable inside the network, do you need to set requires_grad=True or it is by default True like the parameters of prefabricated layers?

Comment: Thanks! very well explained. One more question, when you define your own Tensor variable inside the network, do you need to set requires_grad=True or it is by default True like the parameters of prefabricated layers?